# NodeJS SQL Server - Running multiple queries with Async

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to run two separate queries in a NodeJS Lambda Function. The first inserts a single record, and will return an order number used in the subsequent queries. The second query needs to insert `n` records (order items), so I've been trying to execute those utilizing the `async` node library as you can see below.

I'm running into issues where it's either not executing those queries at all, or is only inserting a single record versus `n` records. I'm feeding it right now with an API request, so the referenced `items` array should have two indexes in it, resulting in two iterations.

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const async = require('async');

(function() {

// ——- Database support ——- //

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback)
{
    const config = {
        user: 'my_user',
        password: 'my_pass',
        server: 'my_serv',
        database: 'my_db',
        options: {
          encrypt: true 
        }
    };

    // Request Body
    var body = event;
    var items = body[1]["items"];
    var addDateTimeRaw = body[1]["created_at"];
    var splitDateTime = addDateTimeRaw.split(" ");

    // SPROC params
    var CustomerNumber = "1234";
    var OrderDateString = splitDateTime[0];
    var ShipVia = "UPS";
    var FOB = "null";
    var PaymentTerms = "CREDIT CARD";
    var Discount = "0";
    var OrderAmount = body[1]["total_price"].cents;
    var PONumber = body[1]["_id"];
    var Comment = "I am a comment";
    var SalesPerson = "WA";
    var IsShippingSameAsBilling = "X";
    var TaxableAmount = body[1]["total_value"].cents;
    var TaxState = "my_state";
    var AddDate = splitDateTime[0];
    var AddTime = splitDateTime[1];
    var WebOrderNumber = body[1]["_id"];

    sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            const req = new sql.Request();
            req.query('EXEC InsertOrder @CustomerNumber = "' + CustomerNumber + '", @OrderDateString = "' + OrderDateString + '", @ShipVia = "' + ShipVia + '", @FOB = "' + FOB + '", @PaymentTerms = "' + PaymentTerms + '", @Discount = "' + Discount + '", @OrderAmount = "' + OrderAmount + '", @PONumber = "' + PONumber + '", @Comment = "' + Comment + '", @SalesPerson = "' + SalesPerson + '", @IsShippingSameAsBilling = "' + IsShippingSameAsBilling + '", @TaxableAmount = "' + TaxableAmount + '", @TaxState = "' +TaxState + '", @AddDate = "' + AddDate + '", @AddTime = "' + AddTime + '", @WebOrderNumber = "' + WebOrderNumber + '";', (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    var OrderNumber = result.recordset[0].sono;
                    insertOrderItems(OrderNumber);
                    sql.close();
                    context.succeed(result.recordset)
                    return JSON.stringify(items);
                }
             });

             function insertOrderItems(OrderNumber) {
                 async.forEachOf(items, function (item, i, inner_callback){
                     //var itemNumber = item["sku"];
                    var ItemNumber = "5678";
                    var DiscountPercent = "0";
                    var TaxRate = "6";
                    var Quantity = item["quantity"];
                    var ItemSequence = i + 1;
                    var CustomerMemo = "I am a memo";
                    var UnitPrice = "6.00";
                    var ssql = 'EXEC InsertOrderItems @OrderNumber = "' + OrderNumber + '", @ItemNumber = "' + ItemNumber + '", @DiscountPercent = "' + DiscountPercent + '", @TaxRate = "' + TaxRate + '", @Quantity = "' + Quantity + '", @ItemSequence = "' + ItemSequence + '", @CustomerMemo = "' + CustomerMemo + '", @UnitPrice = "' + UnitPrice + '";';
                    req.query(ssql, function(err, members, fields){
                        if(!err){
                            console.log(members);
                            //context.succeed(members.recordset)
                            inner_callback(null);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Error while performing Query");
                            inner_callback(err);
                        };
                    });
                }, function(err){
                    if(err){
                      //handle the error if the query throws an error
                      callback(err);
                    }else{
                      //whatever you wanna do after all the iterations are done
                      callback(null);
                    }
                });
             }

        }
    });

    sql.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    });

};
}());
```

Why might that function call to the async SQL query not be executing? I'm attempting to keep the same SQL connection open for both of the executed queries.

Answer (score 1):

The `async` is not a main issue. I patched some places but it still worse.
Why do you not learn step-by-step?

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const async = require('async');

const config = { ... };

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Use default object with props or check existing of every props  
    var body = (event && event[1]) instanceof Object ? event[1] : {items: [], created_at: ' ', _id: ...}; 

    var items = body.items || []; // Always use default value
    var [addDate, addTime] = (created_at || '').split(' '); // Use destructuring assignment

    // SPROC params
    var CustomerNumber = "1234";
    var OrderDateString = splitDateTime[0];
    var ShipVia = "UPS";
    var FOB = "null";
    var PaymentTerms = "CREDIT CARD";
    var Discount = "0";
    var OrderAmount = parseFloat((body.total_price || {}).cents) || 0; // total_price can be non-object and it'll fall your app
    var PONumber = body[1]["_id"];
    var Comment = "I am a comment";
    var SalesPerson = "WA";
    var IsShippingSameAsBilling = "X";
    var TaxableAmount = body[1]["total_value"].cents;
    var TaxState = "my_state";
    var WebOrderNumber = body._id;

    sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        // Early quit to avoid {}-ladder
        if (err) 
            return callback(err);

        const req = new sql.Request();

        // Never do like this. Read about sql-injection. Use placeholders.
        req.query('EXEC ost_InsertOrder @CustomerNumber = "' + ..., (err, result) => {
            if (err)
                return callback(err);

            var OrderNumber = result.recordset.length && result.recordset[0].sono; // You must be sure that result has rows

            // You should read about async-code
            insertOrderItems(OrderNumber); // Here you start to insert items
            sql.close(); // But before it'll success you close connection.
            context.succeed(result.recordset);

            // I didn't see definition of items.
            // Return? For what?
            return JSON.stringify(items);
         });
         ...
        }
    });

    sql.on('error', callback);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Aikon! This is super helpful. I actually went back and re-wrote this using the npm MSSQL docs to have both queries fully-async. At the time of posting, this was a gigantic mess, so I'm very appreciative of you helping point things out. I'll post an update shortly.